# onUserLogin and onUserAfterLogin events don't seem to fire

Tags: plugin, user

I am trying to write a simple plugin that runs after the user logs in to the system.  I have written content and authentication plugins before with no issues.  In this case I have stripped the plugin down to the following and still see no evidence it ever runs.

```
<?php 
  defined('_JEXEC') or die; 
  class Plgtest extends JPlugin {   
    public function onUserLogin($user, $options = array()) {
      JFactory::getApplication()->enqueueMessage('I Ran!.', 'message');   
    } 
  } 
 ?>
```

I have tried both the onUserLogin and onUserAfterLogin events and never see the plugin run.  My xml file is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<extension type="plugin" version="3.0" method="upgrade" group="user">
    <name>User - test</name>
    <creationDate>2014-07-19</creationDate>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <releaseDate>2014-07-19</releaseDate>
    <releaseType>First release!</releaseType>
    <author>me</author>
    <authorEmail>me@me.com</authorEmail>
    <authorUrl>www.me.com</authorUrl>
    <copyright>(c) 2014 me</copyright>
    <description>test</description>
    <files>
    <filename plugin="test">test.php</filename>
    </files>
    <config>            
        <fields name="params">
            <fieldset name="general_settings" label="Connection Settings">
                <field name="host" type="text" default="127.0.0.1" label="Host" description="Database host." />
                <field name="database" type="text" default="" label="Database" description="Database name." />
                <field name="prefix" type="text" default="" label="Prefix" description="Database prefix, may be blank." />
                <field name="user" type="text" default="" label="User" description="User name." />
                <field name="password" type="password" default="" label="Password" description="User password." />
            </fieldset>
        </fields>
    </config>
</extension>
```

Any help or example code from a working plugin would be appreciated.  Never had such problems before, hopefully whatever I am missing is painfully obvious.

Also, the connection settings are irrelevant in this example.  The real plugin connects to an external database.

Comment: Maybe its the name of the plugin? I once had one as plg_my_test and it wouldn't run until i renamed it plg_mytest

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't mention a Joomla version so I'm assuming 3.x, although this should be pretty much the same for 2.5.x.

As mentioned your plugin's class name is incorrect, the name of the class is derived from the plugin name and type, and the file/folder naming conventions & structure for the plugin help Joomla find and load the right php files.

If your plugin is in `/plugins/user/` and it's folder is `test`, main file is `test.php` (with a `test.xml` file) then your class should be called `PlgUserTest`.

`JPluginHelper` basically loads a category of plugins (`authentication`, `captcha`, `content`,... `user` etc) in `::importPlugin()` based on the type e.g. `user`. First it gets the published plugins from the database (so your plugin needs to be registered with Joomla, this happens in the install process or you can use the "Discover" option in the Extension Manager).

The `importPlugin()` method then loops through the published plugins matching for the `$type` it's been asked to load, for each match it `import()`'s the plugins main `php` file by building the `$path` to it like this:

```
$path = JPATH_PLUGINS . '/' . $plugin->type . '/' . $plugin->name . '/' . $plugin->name . '.php';
```

From that you can see the path to your file should be:

```
/plugins/users/test/test.php
```

Once it's got the file, it then loads the class by creating the `$className` from the attributes it already has using this line:

```
$className = 'Plg' . $plugin->type . $plugin->name;
```

From this you can see that your class name should be `PlgUserTest`

Answer (score 0):

I think that if you make your plugin part of the `user` group, you need to change the class name to:

```
PlgUserTest
```